# Extract mean from categorical data type column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, analytics

For example have this table:

```
list_1=[['1','y',474.0],
        ['2','n',482.0],
       ['3','n',564.0,],
       ['4','y',549.0,],
       ['5','y',551.0,],
       ['6','y',555.0,],
       ['7','n',600.0,],
       ['8','y',357.0,],
       ['9','y',542.0,],
       ['10','n',462.0,],
       ['11','n',513.0,],
       ['12','y',526.0,]]
labels=['id','order_?','hours_spend']
df=pd.DataFrame(list_1,columns=labels)
df
```

Result:

```
    id  order_? hours_spend
0   1   y        474.0
1   2   n        482.0
2   3   n        564.0
3   4   y        549.0
4   5   y        551.0
5   6   y        555.0
6   7   n        600.0
7   8   y        357.0
8   9   y        542.0
9   10  n        462.0
10  11  n        513.0
11  12  y        526.0
```

I'm going to divide the hours_spend column to 3 groups with NTILE method without lables:

```
df['ntile']=pd.qcut(df['hours_spend'],3)
df
```

Result:

```
id  order_? hours_spend      ntile
0   1   y   474.0        (356.999, 502.667]
1   2   n   482.0        (356.999, 502.667]
2   3   n   564.0        (549.667, 600.0]
3   4   y   549.0        (502.667, 549.667]
4   5   y   551.0        (549.667, 600.0]
5   6   y   555.0        (549.667, 600.0]
6   7   n   600.0        (549.667, 600.0]
7   8   y   357.0        (356.999, 502.667]
8   9   y   542.0        (502.667, 549.667]
9   10  n   462.0        (356.999, 502.667]
10  11  n   513.0        (502.667, 549.667]
11  12  y   526.0        (502.667, 549.667]
```

Now i have column 'ntile' with data type 'category':

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 12 entries, 0 to 11
Data columns (total 4 columns):
id             12 non-null object
order_?        12 non-null object
hours_spend    12 non-null float64
ntile          12 non-null category
dtypes: category(1), float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 556.0+ bytes
```

How I can add new column with mean of range in 'ntile' column ??

Comment: what do you mean by *mean of range*? What is your expected output?

Comment: In each row in new column will be average of range in each 'ntile' row

Comment: I get the new column part, but not sure what *mean/average* of range is.

Comment: The sum of two numbers divide by the number of numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply define it as:

```
df['mean_ntile'] = (df['ntile'].apply(lambda x: x.left).astype(int) + df['ntile'].apply(lambda x: x.right).astype(int))/2
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    id order_?  hours_spend               ntile  mean_ntile
0    1       y        474.0  (356.999, 502.667]       429.0
1    2       n        482.0  (356.999, 502.667]       429.0
2    3       n        564.0    (549.667, 600.0]       574.5
3    4       y        549.0  (502.667, 549.667]       525.5
4    5       y        551.0    (549.667, 600.0]       574.5
5    6       y        555.0    (549.667, 600.0]       574.5
6    7       n        600.0    (549.667, 600.0]       574.5
7    8       y        357.0  (356.999, 502.667]       429.0
8    9       y        542.0  (502.667, 549.667]       525.5
9   10       n        462.0  (356.999, 502.667]       429.0
10  11       n        513.0  (502.667, 549.667]       525.5
11  12       y        526.0  (502.667, 549.667]       525.5
```

As @ALlolz suggested an easier way is:

```
df['mean_ntile'] = df['ntile'].apply(lambda x: x.mid)
```

Comment: Is not work:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' and 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'

Comment: Sorry, fixed. Try this

Comment: Thanks @ALlolz you know I have a saying, the less you know, the more you code.

Comment: Turns out this kind of an apply is very fast. I have no idea why ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: thanks for good solution
what is x.mid ?? this work only with 'categorical' data type ?

Comment: No, it is meant to work with intervals. It is the exact same thing as the previous code, were we extract the left and right values for the interval, sum them and divide by 2. `mid` comes to replace this.